# 128GB in Rpi3b+?

Tags: video, pi-3b+

I’m thinking about getting a Samsung 128GB microsd as they’re cheap in Amazon and I assume not fake/shanzai.
But can the  Rpi3b+ use this?
Also it is speed 10 and U3 rated because there’s no longer any speed 3 for sale.

Answer (score 4):

According to [eLinux](https://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards) these cards with the respective part numbers (last column) should work fine.

```
Samsung EVO         microSDXC   128     10              MB-MP128GA/AM 
Samsung EVO PLUS    microSDXC   128     10              MB-MC128DA/AMZ 
Samsung PRO+        microSDXC   128     10 UHS-I U3     MB-MD128DA/AM
```

Besides these a few others, e.g. SanDisk are listed as working.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Linux device up running, you can use this [F3 - an alternative to h2testw](http://oss.digirati.com.br/f3) utility to check the integrity of your microSD and/or USB storage against the real size of its storage. It is available on debian Stretch. The software also prints out the R/W speed on-demand when checking/testing the storage. This way, you will not only know its integrity, but also will know its R/W performance throughputs. I use it all the time when I acquire any new (micro)SD cards and/or any USB memory sticks.