# Samsung 128GB EVO Plus File System problems

Tags: sd-card, pi-3b+

I just received my first RPi 3B+ board today and have tried to use it with a Samsung EVO Plus 128GB u3 card

I downloaded Raspbian Stretch Lite (June 2018) and used Etcher to flash the cards.

After initially booting and shutting down (`sudo shutdown -h now`) I noticed that they it hangs on `Reached Target Shutdown`. After waiting around 10 mins, the screen goes blank but the red light stays on. There is no response to the keyboard. After pulling the plug and rebooting, there are quite a few errors:

```
Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-partuuid/98a4ba55-01.)
Dependency failed for /boot.
Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
Timed out waiting for device dev-serial1.device.
```

Then it says `You are in emergency mode` and it goes into an `fsck`, finishes around 20% and ends saying:

```
Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked. See sulogin(8) man page for more details. Press ENTER to continue.
```

Then after a few more minutes, it seems to finish booting and gives the login prompt.

According to answer to [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/84683/128gb-in-rpi3b) question, the card should work fine, so I am not sure how to proceed. I actually have 2 RPis and 3 cards and the same thing happens with all.

[image]
[image]

Comment: so, do you have a EVO+ or EVO Plus (yes, they are two different things) - i.e. what part number? `MB-MC128GA/AM` or `MB-MC128DA/AMZ` or something else?

Comment: @JaromandaX EVO Plus - I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly a SD Card issue. I assume you bought them all from the same place ? They even *look* counterfeit to me.

Download h2testw (it's in German and English) to check for errors.

I will be very surprised if this is not the problem. Where did you buy them ?

--------  UPDATE -----------

Here is a real one, which works with no problem in the RPi 3B+ for me. Bought from [mymemory.co.uk](http://www.mymemory.co.uk) Note, this doesn't mean that ones "Made in Taiwan" are fake. These companies has factories all over
[image]

[image]

Comment: You are right. They are fake cards. I bought them from Ebay and the seller refunded me immediately after I complained.